# PHP: file_exists don't work when file name is in non-latin language

Tags: php, utf-8, file-exists

i have the following code

```
    $file = WWW_ROOT."/upload/files/".$id.".plist";
/* $file=iconv('utf-8', 'latin1', $file); */
/*  print_r($file);exit; */
if (file_exists($file)) {
  //downloading
}
```

the problem occure when $id have something like جدة it can't find the file although it's exist .. what can i add to code to convert the $id to utf-8 and read the file on disk?

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove the `iconv` ... You need somthing like this ....

```
$id = "file_å";
$file = __DIR__ . "/" . $id . ".plist";
$file = iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', $file);

/* print_r($file);exit; */
if (file_exists($file)) {
    // downloading
    print("OK");
}
```

Comment: it gives 
 iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string [APP/Controller/TestController.php, line 48]